# How to we ping to check accessibility of a website or a server from different locations?

Tags: networking

Do we have an online utility which can be used to ping by selecting locations?

Comment: You may re-ask this question on https://superuser.com . It has nothing to do with Engineering.

Comment: Can I move it to superuser.com?

Comment: I have created a new one here https://superuser.com/questions/1301877/how-to-we-ping-to-check-accessibility-of-a-website-or-a-server-from-different-lo. Should I delete this one?

Comment: Only mods can move questions, but they typically don't do it, because it causes territorial conflicts between them. Yes, you can ask duplicated question, if the first version is closed on any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. There is plenty of test locations. https://www.dotcom-tools.com/ping-test.aspx

Comment: Great!. This was of some help. I am looking for some specific locations like Fremont-CA-US. Actually, my requirement is I want to choose the location and also if I can check the certificate expiration details.

Comment: Then try with some VPN. And manually ping the server.

Comment: This site does not require VPN https://www.dotcom-tools.com/ping-test.aspx but displays the result from different locations. All I want is an option where I can choose the location. If I have to do a manual ping then I need to create at the least 195 servers for each country.